# Asp.net 5 logging not displayed in output window

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I believe I have correctly enabled logging in my Asp.net 5 app, with the following code:

Added the following line to my ConfigureServices method in the Startup.cs:

```
services.AddLogging()
```

Included the AddDebug() in my Configure method

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, TheWorldContextSeedData seedContext, ILoggerFactory logger)
    {
        logger.AddDebug(LogLevel.Information);

        app.UseStaticFiles();// allow self hosting to use static files i.e. files in the wwwroot

        //listen for mvc requests
        app.UseMvc(config =>
        {
            config.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",//optional id
                defaults: new { controller = "App", action = "Index" }
                );
        });

        seedContext.EnsureSeedData();
    }
```

However, I cannot see any information in the output window under Debug. In this case I am looking for logging information in regards to what Entity Framework is doing i.e. Which command it is running.

Any ideas would be very helpful, thanks

Comment: `AddDebug` will only show the log output in the debug window when actually debugging. You need to use `AddConsole` if you want the output to appear in the normal output.

Comment: Take note there is added logging functionality coming between Beta8 and RC1 which should come out at the end of November. According to the latest ASP.NET 5 community standup this logging functionality  deals specifically with EF logging were you can see the SQL commands. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CxuSmw2-BSI&list=PL0M0zPgJ3HSftTAAHttA3JQU4vOjXFquF&index=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In this case I am looking for logging information in regards to what Entity Framework is doing i.e. Which command it is running.

The log level for Entity Framework was changed from *Information* to *Debug*, as this usually outputs *a lot* debugging information which isn’t particulary useful in the long run. The new behavior also matches the [logging guidelines](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/wiki/Guidelines) more properly.

The change was made shortly after the release of beta 7 and was brought up in [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3081). Starting with beta 8, you need to set your log level to *Debug* in order to see the output from Entity Framework. See also [this related issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3624).

Comment: Thanks, this is now showing me the information I expected. Also very useful links, I will look into those in more detail

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the line

```
services.AddLogging.
```

Logging is already available from the bootstrap code

You can see debug logging in VS 2015 if you attached to the DNX process or by running the project (F5). 
See `output window` and select `debug`.

There should be a lot of messages about thread exits etc